# How to get number of ticks from rxjs Observable

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs5

How to get how many times this observable ran

```
   this.clock = Observable.interval(1000).map(function(value){
     if(value == 0){
       return  value * 100 / 60;
     }
     return value * 100 / 60;
    }).take(61);
```

I want to get that this Observable ran 1 or 2 or 3.. times and display each time with interpolation in template

if I'm doing this, it would return percentage variable to be NaN

```
this.clock.subscribe(function(x){
              console.log(x);
              console.log("percentage " + this.percentage);
              this.percentage = this.percentage + 1;
    })
```

Comment: `this.percentage` returns NaN if you don't initially set `this.percentage = 0`.  It's because `undefined + anyNumber = NaN`

Comment: Thank you, nice information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you can create a variable which will responsible for storing count of how many time observable ran. Then apply `async` over that value to display value returned by observable.

```
{{ clockCount | async }}
```

**Code**

```
clockCount: any;
count: number = 0;
ngOnInit(){
    this.clock = Observable.interval(1000).map((value) => {
       if(value == 0){
         return  value * 100 / 60;
       }
       return value * 100 / 60;
    }).take(61);
    this.clockCount = this.clock.do(() => this.count = ++this.count);
}
```

Comment: Its being manipulated in the map function what i want is to display each time this observable will run like if it run first time it should get me 1 and i will be able to display that into view, the clock is returning percentage not sequential integer like 1, 2, 3 and so on

Comment: why this code would return percentage variable to be NaN, see updated question

Comment: This looks pretty good, but I think you mean `.do(() => ++this.count)`.

Comment: If I'm doing this, this.percentage = this.clock.do(() => this.percentage++); in the constructor function where stream created, and displaying {{percentage}} im getting objectObject at view

Comment: @blackHawk Yes, it should be `this.conut`. In this `this.percentage = this.clock.do(() => this.percentage++);` you shouldn't be manipulating `percentage` anymore to `number` value, it has observable value, check out my answer what I did..

Comment: you are displaying clockcounter, what happens to count++, will its value be update?

Comment: @blackHawk If you want to display the count value in your template just do {{ count }} and each time your function runs the template will update displaying the most recent value for `count`

Comment: BTW how to force interval operator to start from 1 instead of 0, or any other operator for emitting value from one to 60 with the interval of 1 second